# Adding default address(shipping) to when customer signup

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, dependency-injection

I'm new to Magento 2, no e-commerce experience before.

So I'm working on making this module that should 'add default shipping address to customer when they sign up'.

During some research and learning magento 2, I found this event and observer + dependency injection could help me able to get it happen.

BUT, my code is not working.. need some help!

here are my codes and structure.

my observer.

```
<?php
namespace Threeon\DefaultAddress\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddressAdder implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $addressFactory;

public function __construct(Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory)
{
    $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');

    /*$addresses[] = $observer->getEvent()->getAddresses();*/
    $address = $this->addressFactory->create();

    $address->setCountryId('HR')
        //->setRegionId('1') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
        ->setPostcode('31000')
        ->setCity('Osijek')
        ->setTelephone('0038511223344')
        ->setCompany('GMI')
        ->setStreet('NO:12 Lake View')
        ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
    try{
        $address->save();
        $customer->setAddress($address);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }
    // TODO: Implement execute() method.
}

}

?>
```

event.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
```

Comment: I think it is better to insert code rather than images for search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out that I was messing with wrong event :/

It works now with new event and modified code as this:

events.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="customer_register_success">
   <observer name="AddressAdderObserver" instance="Threeon\DefaultAddress\Observer\AddressAdder"/>
  </event>
</config>
```

observer:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddressAdder implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $manager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)

{
    $this->manager = $objectManager;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

    $address = $this->manager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\Address');
    $address = $address->setData('parent_id', $customer->getId())
        ->setData('is_active', '1')
        ->setData('city', 'ny')
        ->setData('company', 'ibuyr')
        ->setData('country_id', 'US')
        ->setData('firstname', $customer->getFirstName())
        ->setData('lastname', $customer->getLastName())
        ->setData('postcode', '07024')
        ->setData('region', 'New York')
        ->setData('region_id', '43')
        ->setData('street', '103 waterside')
        ->setData('telephone', '200-300-1111')
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
    try{
        $address->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }
    return $this;
}
}
?>
```